# Using convert or mogrify to merge multiple PNG files into a single multi-page TIFF file

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

Say I have a folder `foo` with multiple PNG files. Is there a way to use `convert` or `mogrify` to merge the PNG files into a single TIFF file?

I have tried:

```
mogrify -format tiff -adjoin *.png
```

but I get `unrecognized option -adjoin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Version: ImageMagick 6.6.1-5 2010-04-23 Q16`, this works just fine:

```
convert *.png all.tiff
```

Answer (score 5):

To merge them into a single file as an image sequence you can use the answer given by Matthias Osidio.

-append creates a single image where the images in the original set are stacked top-to-bottom.

```
mogrify -append *.png output.tiff
```